# Flask mail only sending to certain domains

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have a Flask application that uses an email server at Bluehost to send mail. Flask-mail successfully sends the email (I don't see any errors in the logs) however the email never arrives to Gmail accounts (not in spam or anything either). However, it does arrive at other domains.

Any idea what may be causing this or where to look for errors?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have email host name you are sending from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just check your SPF records.

It seems that your sending mail server has no SPF record. This is why Gmail is probably blocking email from you mail server.

Check here for more info: [this](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3Abox874.bluehost.com&run=toolpage)

Comment: Forgive the newbie question, but this seems something I can rectify myself via the cpanel?

Comment: possibly, but i would lodge a ticket with the host to sort it out. They should be easily able to sort it out